# Convolutions of two functions

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, convolution

I am having trouble understanding how you take the convolution of two functions.

For example, if $f_1(x) = x$, with x  ranging from [0,X] how do I solve for $f_2(x)$ when
$$f_2(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f_1(x')f_1(x-x') dx'.$$
Do I need to use an indicator function?

Thanks

Comment: This integral does not converge for your choice of $f_1$.

Comment: Also: I suppose $*$ denotes multiplication and not convolution?

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 1):

in your example you sustitute $f_1(x')=x'$  and $f_1(x-x')=x-x'$ in an analagous way and solve the integral having the $x'$ as your integral's variable.

If the integral converges, you will get a result in terms of x and it will be the convolution of $f_1$ with itself. if the integral dows not converge, you can't make the convolution.